# Creating an array object with methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the Adobe Javascript DOM most objects classes have a plural class which contains all instances of that object e.g:

Hyperlink (an object for defining a hyperlink object)
Hyperlinks (an object for defining all instances  of hyperlink objects)

Other than containing all instances of the singular object, the plural classes has its own properties and methods (so it is not an array).

This seems fairly straight forward to replicate within Javascript, however Adobe is able to use the following syntax:

```
var singleHyperlink = Hyperlinks[0];
```

They are able to treat the object as if it were an array. Passing it a numerator inside square braces will return a single objet.

How are they doing this?

Comment: Without doing any research, it sounds like Hyperlinks is an array of Hyperlink objects.

Comment: They could just be using numeric keys, for example `{'0': someObj}`.

Comment: "the plural classes has its own properties and methods (so it is not an array)" Why does that not allow it to be an Array? Array objects can definitely have their own properties and methods.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, that's probably the answer.

Comment: That true, I didn't think about that... So the Hyperlinks class probably extends the Array class and probably has validation methods that only allow items that are of object type Hyperlink. Does this sound right?